# Advantage of GET/POST-only Models Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

This might be a stupid question but considering I have an API that only performs GET/POST requests but no PUT nor DELETE, what is the advantage of defining models in that case? (If the user can only search items in the database but not insert anything). I surely didn't understand it well.

Comment: What do you mean by defining models? vs what other approach are you considering?

Comment: I was thinking knowing I'd only query the database and not add anything in it, I wouldn't define the attributes for each model/table.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Identical model definition from ground up** - when working with a known normalized model instead of raw data, its easy for plug and play in case of
   changes in business or model. A thoroughly componentized to the
   lowest level - what you see is what you get.
   Using raw data instead of model with schema may cause
   inconsistencies across the application (in model validations for example).
2. **Model validations** - by using models you can validate the given model (in your case in the POST requests) against its schema -
   required attributes, attribute types and [advanced validations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations).
3. **Out-of-the-box database querying** - advanced querying using [Waterline Query Language](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language)

Answer (score 0):

The models are there so you can have control over your app, You can leave the API without models, but if you need to post and get a boolean field it is gonna be recognized as string, so you will have to define that attribute in the model. If you only need string type fields you dont need the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, got it. I was wondering : is there any tool on Sails that allows you to generate models from the database, instead of writing them one by one?